# Problema no parâmetro de uma função

Tags: c, funções, recursão

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  
int pos_setinha(int x);
void menu(int x);

int main()
{int x=0;
do
{
    menu(pos_setinha(x));
}
while(1);
}
int pos_setinha(int x)
{   x=0;
char C;
    C=getch();
    switch(C)
    {
    case 72:
        x++;
        break;
    case 80:
        x--;
        break;
    }
return x;
    }

void menu(int x)
 {if(x==0)
    printf("0");
if(x==1)
    printf("1");
if(x==2)
    printf("2");
 }
```

Estou tendo problemas para salvar o novo valor do x após ele passar pela função pos_setinha, a função sempre retorna ao inicio da função quando o x é 0, como posso corrigir isso?

Comment: O seu objetivo é que a função `pos_setinha` modifique o valor de `x` ? se for o caso, `x = pos_setinha(x);` resolve o problema. No entanto o `x=0;` no inicio dela está a mais.

Answer (score 2):

Olá, eu acho que não ficou muito claro o que você desejava com o problema, dá próxima vez tente dar exemplos melhores do que você quer e do que está acontecendo, além de explicar melhor o que o programa faz ou deveria fazer, dessa forma fica mais fácil para a gente te ajudar, de qualquer forma vamos a solução e ao que eu entendi que você queria.

Primeiro o erro que você está tendo se deve ao fato de que você não está armazenando o valor da variável `x` em nenhum lugar, a primeira coisa que devemos fazer é arrumar isso, para isso é simples, devemos apenas olhar na função (ou rotina), `main` e `pos_setinha`.

Este é o seu código:

```
int main()
{
    int x=0;

    do
    {
        menu(pos_setinha(x)); // veja que você não armazena o valor
                              // retornado da função em lugar algum,
                              // desta forma ele é perdido, e o q você
                              // manda para a sua função é apenas um x = 1 ou -1;
    }while(1);

 // Também esta faltando um return 0 aqui, 
 // desta forma a função main não retorna nada para o sistema.
}
```

Agora vamos olha na função `pos_setinha`:

```
int pos_setinha(int x)
{
    char C;
    C=getch();

    x=0; // Como você pode ver aqui você atribui 0 ao seu X desta forma perdendo o
         // valor que está contido nele, e também assim fazendo com que
         // sua função sempre retorne 1 ou -1, nunca retornando 2 ou 0
         // como o desejado.

    switch(C)
    {
    case 72:
        x++;
        break;
    case 80:
        x--;
        break;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Então neste momento Jose eu te peço para que não olhe ainda o resto da resposta, e pare e pense no que deve ser feito para resolver estes erros, tente primeiro resolver isso sozinho, pois assim a chance de você entender melhor o seu erro será maior, do que apenas olhar um resultado já pronto okay ;).

Continuando, caso você não tenha chegado em uma resposta aqui está a a minha.
A primeira coisa que deve ser feita é atribuir o valor retornado pela função a uma variável, assim o valor não será perdido, o segundo é tirar aquele x = 0 da função `pos_setinha`, e a terceira colocar o `return 0` na função `main` assim o programa ficara da seguinte forma:

```
int pos_setinha(int x)
{
    char C = getch(); // Foi tirado o X = 0, para o valor não se perder
                      // e note que você pode por o getch junto com a 
                      // declaração da variável C.

    switch(C)
    {
    case 72:
        x++;
        break;
    case 80:
        x--;
        break;
    }

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    do
    {
        x = pos_setinha(x); // Dessa forma o valor será guardado na
                            // variável X.
        menu(x);
    }while(1);

 return 0; // return 0 foi adicionado.
}
```

Agora o que você deve estar se perguntando é se o seu problema acabou, e a resposta é não, o seu programa tem mais um problema que é o [buffer](https://programacaodescomplicada.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/aula-81-limpar-o-buffer/) não estar limpo, então é necessário que você o limpe, há varias formas de fazer isso a que eu utilizarei aqui é a mesma que está no vídeo que eu linkei a palavra buffer, assim ficará fácil de você entender.
Então para fazer a limpeza basta que antes de fazer a leitura do caractere 
você o utilize a função `setbuf`, dessa forma você limpará o buffer, então o programa ficará de tal forma:

```
int pos_setinha(int x)
{
    setbuf(stdin, NULL); // Aqui você estará atribuindo o valor NULL, ou 
                         // seja, 0 ao stdin, que é o buffer do teclado,
                         // assim estará o limpando.
    char C = getch();

    switch(C)
    {
    case 72:
        x++;
        break;
    case 80:
        x--;
        break;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Agora você deve estar pensando que acabou, e você está certo, acabou de começar, rs, falando sério, há também mais algumas coisas que podem ser feitas, dado o fato que você está utilizando caracteres você não precisa colocar o numero da tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), pode colocar o caractere direto, mas lembre-se de colocar entre apóstrofes ('letra'), dessa forma sabendo que 72 e 80 são respectivamente H e P, o programa ficará assim.

```
int pos_setinha(int x)
{
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    char C = getch();

    switch(C)
    {
    case 'H':
        x++;
        break;
    case 'P':
        x--;
        break;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Note que assim o programa fica mais intuitivo para quem olha, e assim sabemos se você esta trabalhando apenas com `int` ou `char`, porque essa era umas das ambiguidades do seu programa, eu não sabia, e ainda não sei, se você queria trabalhar com `char` e olhou na tabela [ASCII](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) os valores e colocou, ou se você queria trabalhar com números, porque se for o segundo caso você terá que mudar o tipo da variável C para `int`, mas considerei que você queria trabalhar com caracteres.

Por ultimo mas não menos importante também há a função menu, da para fazer uma mudança nela, já que ela serve para imprimir o valor de uma variável não é necessário que você faça aqueles `if`s, basta apenas imprimir a variável, assim a função ficará de tal maneira:

```
void menu(int x)
{
    printf("%i\n", x);
}
```

Agora está tudo terminado. Só mais uma coisa tente não declarar as funções em cima da `main` e fazer a definição embaixo, isso cria um código Spaghetti, então utilize sempre boas práticas de programação, um exemplo de como eu acho que o código deveria ser:

```
#include <stdio.h> // Note que eu tirei a stdlib, pois você não estava
                   // utilizando-a.

void menu(int x)
{
    printf("%i\n", x);
}

int pos_setinha(int x)
{
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    char C =  getchar();

    switch(C)
    {
    case 'H':
        ++x;
        break;

    case 'P':
        --x;
        break;
    }

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 0;

    do
    {
        x = pos_setinha(x);
        menu(x);
    }while(1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

É isso, espero ter ajudado, qualquer coisa só perguntar, e boa sorte nos estudos de programação.

Answer (score 0):

A função `getch()` é utilizada para ler apenas um caracter.
Para ler mais do que um (um número neste caso) deverá utilizar `scanf`:

```
int cNumber;
scanf("%d\n",&cNumber)
```